Ubuntu after ubdate problem
When i delet python3 my laptop stuck in ubuntu loop. Then i run many code sudo ubdate, pkdg,gdm3 and code for reinstall python. Some of many things i do to fix this problem. Finally i fix this problem come to desktop screen but my terminal and firefox are both lost. And i also can't create folder with mouse it is also lost. How can i come out from this problem?
My ubuntu version is: 20.04.6(Focal Fossa).
I see many question in ubuntu and ans but not for mine. I can't give terminal problem titile beacuse many off them use it.

In your given link i check. But there was to talk about command. Which can help me to fix my problem. But now i have no terminal, so how can i command this. My English is weak please cooperate with it

@karel :Thanks karel its work my terminal option came back. And come a notification software ubdates available important OS and application ubdates ready to install . Do i install it or not

@karel  : my ubuntu many things ar change. Like if i create touch file in desktop it is not show in desktop screen. But in desktop list show it is create.Tell me that  can i came back my old default setting in ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS(Focal Fossa) by using command in terminal. Or i need to go repair shop for this problem. They can use CD and create a new ubuntu i think. Help me what should i do.

Yes, you should accept the prompt to update your installed software. Maybe you got the touch command wrong. Try it like this: cd Desktop/ && touch newfile which shows a new file named newfile on my Ubuntu 24.04 desktop. In any case touch ls created the file, so the problem is not with the terminal, it is with the default Files app. Try using a lightweight app like Thunar. It is a 100% replacement for the Files app except that it doesn't drive you crazy. If you like Thunar and want to use it permanently instead of Files please comment and I will give you the appropriate command.

@karel : i try it like this but it is not shows a new file named new file on my ubuntu 20.04.6 desktop. But in -/Desktop$ ls command it is show newfile. File can create but in screen it is not showing. Ok give me the command i will try it

The command to install Thunar file manager is sudo apt install thunar The command to make Thunar the default file manager is xdg-mime default thunar.desktop inode/directory

I run this command. But in screen no file ar shows. But in files manu i see in Desktop here i can see created file

I think it is happen because my all menu bar not show in screen. In screen here a file name in upper side "Activities". I clik on activities then i can see my menu bar like : Thunderbird mail,Files, Rhythmbox, Show application menu etc

@karel :And also i can't create new folder use mouse click on right side. That i could before. Now if i click right side on mouse here is change background, Display setting, setting, but no terminal option here

@karel : can any command create again new ubuntu 20.04.6LTS (Focal Fossa). I have no any important data on my laptop. Can it be happen reset all file and create again ubuntu wich is like first time i use ubuntu

There is no command that can do that. There is however a backup app called Timeshift which is not installed by default that can do that.

@karel : sorry for disturbing you too much. But in here no one see our problem. And they can't ans well. You are too good on it. And you are very kind person i think. So that you help use lot. Thank you for your help karel

Can you tell me what should i do now

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
